When is quotient of $S^n$ by $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^n$?
I'm wondering when does a quotient of $S^n$ by a free $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action give $\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}^n$. I.e. suppose
$$ F: S^n \to S^n$$
$$F^2(x) = x$$
and $F$ does not fix any point. Then is $S^n / (x \sim F(x)) \cong \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$?

There are fake projective spaces constructed this way (using free topological involutions), they are homotopy equivalent but not homeomorphic to the real projective space.

For instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622280/does-a-fixpoint-free-self-inverse-homeomorphism-define-a-smooth-manifold/3622316#3622316

@MoisheKohan is there a way to show this using $BTop(n)$ characteristic classes? That's interesting, I never thought about it. Thanks for sharing

@AndresMejia: maybe not in dimension 4 but in higher dimensions where there are similar earlier examples (I think in Lopez de Medrano's book on involutions).

thanks ${}{}{}$

@AndresMejia Take a look here: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Fake_real_projective_spaces

@Kevin.S My mistake - the example was wrong so I removed it, but I guess the general question holds

@MoisheKohan actually for my purposes I just want to know that the quotient has the same cohomology ring as real projective n-space, so if I have such an action, is it always homotopy equivalent to the real projective space?
